# How to create a build with Appcelerator Studio

Tags: appcelerator

Please tell me the procedure how to create IPA or APK from Appcelerator Studio.

Also, there are ways to export xcodeproj if cannot export IPA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On top you need to click "run" to show a dropdown with `Package`. Which is the one you need to select.

[image]

From there, select iOS on the dropdown next to it, and follow the guideline. You need at least an indie seat at Appcelerator, and have the proper certificates and provisioning profiles set up as you should with regular iOS development.

Answer (score 0):

Have you gone through the appcelerator docs.

Please refer [Creating Your First Titanium App](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Creating_Your_First_Titanium_App)

[Distributing iOS apps](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Distributing_iOS_apps-section-27595277_DistributingiOSapps-Buildyourapp,embeddingtheprofilewithintheapp'sbundle)

[Distributing Android apps](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Distributing_Android_apps-section-29004925_DistributingAndroidapps-Buildandsignyourapp)

From mentioned your you will get the maximum info about building a Titanium project.